# Meteor - Accounts, how to reset the password?

Tags: jquery, html, mongodb, meteor, passwords

In Meteor, I am using `accounts` package for sessions, here I am trying to implement the custom forgot password & change(reset) password page with the help of `http://steve-adams.me/practical-examples-of-authentication-in-meteor-1-0/` blog. Right now password change & validation is not happening, simply it reloads the page.

How can I implement the custom forgot & change password page?

Comment: If a page is reloading when a form is submitted, you'll want to do e.preventDefault(); where e is the event that occurred. Also, check out the useraccounts package on atmoshpere. Might help you

Comment: @eliezer-steinbock:  Thanku